# httpd error_log is logging errors on running web application on https

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, apache

There is a web application running on Apache Tomcat 5.5 When application is run through https instead of http(below is the url)

```
https://170.21.101.23:2001/appl/
```

then in httpd error_log on IE8, following error is coming(same errors for other files as well):

```
[Tue Aug 07 16:17:46 2012] [error] [client 10.203.128.142] File does not exist: 
/base/pro/ApacheTomcat/instances/Tomcat/webapps/appl/js/test.js 
referer: https://170.21.101.23:2001/appl/sk/Display.html
```

If we check that do reported files exist? Then yes they exist. Application is working absolutely fine. But error_log of httpd is reporting these errors. Howcome these errors are getting logged in error_log.

Following are the mod_jk logs:

```
JkLogFile /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log

JkMount /appl default
JkMount /appl/* default
JkUnMount /appl/*/*.css default
JkUnMount /appl/*/*.html default
JkUnMount /appl/*/*.gif default
JkUnMount /appl/*/*.ico default
JkUnMount /appl/*/*.jpg default
JkUnMount /appl/*/*.png default
JkUnMount /appl/js/* default
```

Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you using Apache httpd? If so, please post your `mod_proxy_(http|ajp)` or `mod_jk` configuration. Include any `Alias`, `ProxyPass(Reverse)`, `JkMount` or related directives.

Comment: Yes I am using Apache httpd and mod_jk configuration I ahve appended in question.

Comment: When happens when you use your web browser to access `https://170.21.101.23:2001/appl/js/test.js`? How about if you use HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Comment: It ask me for download or to save test.js and it is downloaded and opened successfully. If I use Http then no error is coming. Running perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

`mod_jk` uses a separate set of `JkMount` directives for every VirtualHost: if you have the above `JkMount` directives set for your non-HTTPS (e.g. port 80) VirtualHost, then you'll have to configure the identical set of `JkMount` directives in your SSL-enabled VirtualHost. You can also set your `JkMount` directives at the top-level of your `httpd.conf` and then use `JkMountCopy` to copy them into your VirtualHost (which does not happen by default).

Please see the [Tomcat connector documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/apache.html) for more information about configuring `mod_jk`.